# C++\Cli Interlocked::Add for doubles - can't get Interlocked::CompareExchange alternative working

Tags: .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, c++-cli

This is a follow-on to an earlier question that solved the Parallel::For syntax with thread local variables [Parallel::For with local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845818/c-cli-parallelfor-with-thread-local-variable-error-too-many-arguments/23853450#23853450)

The book example I am trying to implement performs a Interlocked::Add on ints, yet my implementation requires doubles. In the referenced code above I implemented a Lock routine, but that doesn't work. So I am now trying to convert a C# example into a C++\Cli class that I can then call as a safe addition of doubles [Interlocked.CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd0811yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

TreadSafe.h

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

ref class ThreadSafe
{
private:
    double totalValue;

public:
    property double Total
    {
        double get()
        {
            return totalValue;
        }
    }
    double AddToTotal(double addend);

    // constructor
    ThreadSafe(void);
};
```

ThreadSafe.cpp

```
// constructor
ThreadSafe::ThreadSafe(void)
{
    totalValue = 0.0;
}

double ThreadSafe::AddToTotal(double addend)
{
    double initialValue, computedValue;
    do
    {
        initialValue = totalValue;
        computedValue = initialValue + addend;
    }
    while (initialValue != Interlocked::CompareExchange(totalValue, computedValue, initialValue));

    return computedValue;
}
```

This I then call in the Class that contains the Parallel:For routine, which is also listed in the referenced post above.

DataCollection.cpp

```
// constructor
DataCollection::DataCollection(Form1^ f1) // takes parameter of type Form1 to give acces to variables on Form1
{
    this->f1 = f1;

    ts = gcnew ThreadSafe();
}

// initialize data set for parallel processing
void DataCollection::initNumbers(int cIdx, int gIdx)
{
    DataStructure^ number;
    numbers = gcnew List<DataStructure^>();

    for (int i = 0; i < f1->myGenome->nGenes; i++)
    {
// creates collection "numbers" with data to be processed in parallel
    }
}

// parallel-for summation of scores
double DataCollection::sumScore()
{
    Parallel::For<double>(0, numbers->Count, gcnew Func<double>(this, &DataCollection::initSumScore),
                                                gcnew Func<int, ParallelLoopState^, double, double>(this, &DataCollection::computeSumScore),
                                                gcnew Action<double>(this, &DataCollection::finalizeSumScore));
    return ts->Total;
}

// returns start value
double DataCollection::initSumScore()
{
    return 0.0;
}

// perform sequence alignment calculation
double DataCollection::computeSumScore(int k, ParallelLoopState^ status, double tempVal)
{
// calls several external methods, but for testing simplified to an assignment only

    tempVal += 1.0;

    return tempVal;
}

// locked addition
void DataCollection::finalizeSumScore(double tempVal)
{
    ts->AddToTotal(tempVal);
}
```

The code compiles and runs, but it doesn't add. It always returns 0.

So I assume my translation / implementation of the C# example is not correct. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you read [An extensible interlocked arithmetic function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/05/16/10526016.aspx) on Raymond Chen's blog yet?  No need to use the lambdas, but do make sure to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yet he too leaves the C++ implementation to the reader. The starting point is very similar to the second reference I mentioned. Anyway, the above works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an extremely simple example using your `ThreadSafe` class.

```
ref class foo
{
public:
  ThreadSafe^ ts;
  foo() {ts = gcnew ThreadSafe();}
  double init() { return 0.0; }
  double add(int i, ParallelLoopState^, double d) { return d + 1.0; }
  void end(double d) { ts->AddToTotal(d); }
};

int main(array<System::String^>^args)
{
  foo^ f = gcnew foo();
  Parallel::For<double>(0,1000000,
    gcnew Func<double>(f, &foo::init),
    gcnew Func<int, ParallelLoopState^, double, double>(f, &foo::add),
    gcnew Action<double>(f, &f::end));
  Console::WriteLine(f->ts->Total);
}
```

I've seen it run with 1, 2 and 4 task threads. Always outputs 1000000 (for this case).

Pretty sure you didn't make a mistake in your `ThreadSafe` class. I'd start looking elsewhere.

With your code as written, `numbers->Count` will equal 0, which will cause the `Parallel::For` to never execute. I assume you've just omitted the code that fills up `numbers`, but if not, that would be one reason it wouldn't work.

Update: Here is an explanation of what I intended to do in my `Parallel:For` loop:
Each task starts at 0. Each call to `Add` adds `1` to the running amount for the task, then, once the task is finished, it writes out its total to the `ThreadSafe` class.

So, instead of calling `AddToTotal` 100 times, I'm only calling it once per task:

- 1 task: AddToTotal called with a value of 100.
- 2 tasks: AddToTotal called with 2 values that are approximately 50, summing to 100.
- 4 tasks: AddToTotal called with 4 values that are approximately 25, summing to 100.

My `add()` function is still thread-safe, because it isn't accessing any values other than the input parameter `d`, which is either the value returned from `init()` (when the task was started) or the value from the previous `add()` for that task.

To prove my point, I added a `Console::WriteLine(d)` to my `end()` function and upped my count to 1000000. I ran it many times and my final count is always 1000000. Here's an abnormal example that still worked: 467922, 454959, 77119. Total 1000000. (first time I've seen 3 tasks).

Of course, now I've just thought about your concern that I'm only calling `AddToTotal` a few times and it may never be called simultaneously.

Here is my update to add() and end():

```
double add(int i, ParallelLoopState^, double d) { return bar->AddToTotal(1.0); }
void end(double d) { Console::WriteLine(d); }
```

Now, all the adds are done in the tasks and `AddToTotal` will be called 1000000 times. `end()` will only output the final number for each task, returned from `AddToTotal` in the last call to `add()`.

I still get 1000000 calls. I do get more tasks, likely because of all the calls to `AddToTotal` now.

So I agree. My first attempt wasn't a good proof that `AddToTotal` was thread-safe. Now, I expect that it is.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Joel! 'numbers->Count' is not empty. Indeed left out the code for clarity. Good to know that the Threadsafe class works, I will need to do some more searching...

Comment: Looked at your example. It looks like you are doing the adding in `add()` with `d + 1.0`, however this should actually be done in the Threadsafe method `AddToTotal()`. So what you are probably seeing is an unsafe addition in `Add()` and the Threadsafe `AddToTotal` doesn't actually work?

Comment: @jdelang Changed my test to call `AddToTotal()` 1000000 times. Haven't had a failure yet.

Comment: Correct. Your example program pointed me to my mistake: in the computeSumScore metod I did an assigment only (tempVal = 1.0) not an actual safe addition with a tread local var like you did. I changed this to tempVal += 1.0 and then it works! I have now updated the methods in my program with this summation and the (elaborate) external sequence alignment and mapping methods and compared the results with the old sequential calculation and I always get the same results. Sufficient proof that it works. Thanks Joel!